# How to include code in the text/sentence in rmarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

is it possible to run the code **outside** the chunk in rmarkdown?

I want to put some text in html and include code, for example:

The biggest sales had `unique(df$city)` last year...

`````
```{r}
some code
````
`````

Comment: Add a leading `r`, i.e. The biggest sales had `\`r unique(df$city)\`` last year.

Answer (score 3):

Inline code:

```
The biggest sales had `r unique(df$city)` last year.
```

https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-4.html